# Nodejs express cookies are not added

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, express

I'm trying to build a nodejs app and I have to define cookies. This is some of the code:

```
var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
...
app.get('/', routes.indexGET);
app.post('/login', routes.loginPOST);
app.post('/number', routes.numberPOST);
...
res.cookie('number', req.body.number, {secure: true, httpOnly: true, maxAge: 1209600000});
console.log(req.cookies); //Returns {}
```

Why isn't the cookie added? I know that this question has been asked here but I didn't really fined any fine answer. Even "correct" answers (put the cookieParser before the router) wasn't helpful. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure why, but it doesn't work for me too if `secure: true` option used in `res.cookie('number', req.body.number, {secure: true, httpOnly: true, maxAge: 1209600000})`

Don't use it and it's going to work... I guess using it needs a TLS connection established....

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I added secure false, but still it didn't work. Can you please give an example of a simple route with complete configuration that sends a cookie?

Comment: It depends on many factors. What version of expressjs do you use? For version 4.x+ you have to use [cookie-parser middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser) after using it you'll able to have fields `req.cookies.name` and method `res.cookie(name, value)`. As well, in version 4.11.0+ you can use `res.append('Set-Cookie', 'foo=bar; Path=/; HttpOnly')` to set multiple cookies fields. Check out api reference http://expressjs.com/